# How to Convert datetime from one timezone to another timezone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, extjs5

I need to convert from one timezone to another timezone in my project.

I am able to convert from my current timezone to another but not from a different timezone to another.

For example I am in India, and I am able to convert from India to US using Date d=new Date(); and assigning it to a calendar object and setting the time zone.

However, I cannot do this from different timezone to another timezone. For example, I am in India, but I am having trouble converting timezones from the US to the UK.

Answer (score 0):

The easy and fast way is to use an external library. I recommend moment.js. once installed you can convert pretty easily and reliably through their ready-made functions

Comment: Moment also helps in converting from local to another timezone. But i need from one timezone to another not from local to another timezone